# An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/hello.html]

Tags: java, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
       xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    <title>Hello Spring Boot</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 th:text="${message}"></h2>
<h1>Welcome to Spring Boot with Intellij IDEA</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Above This is my HTML Code which I am getting error code

```
  Mon Jan 04 00:24:01 EST 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/hello.html]" - line 4, col 7)
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/hello.html]" - line 4, col 7)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:239)``
```

These are the solutions I have tried.

I did not bother putting the un-important parts which are the first 3 line that are giving me errors.

I added

```
xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org"
```

and even

```
xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org"
```

as well as

```
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
```

none of the three above have worked

I have have changed my controller around a bit on the java side which looks the code below

```
    @Controller
public class WebController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(HttpServletRequest request){

        System.out.println("Saying hello world Spring Boot....");
        request.setAttribute("message", "Greetings");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

This error is unclear to me, I believed it was something on my end but, sometimes it is possible that you must start the project from scratch in order to get things working again.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running fine in my machine. You forgot to add www in

```
 xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org"
```

So that you should add this

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Comment: Remember that I said i used www and a version where I do not use www but I see what you did different now.       xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"        this is what I put and you took out the 'th', which i see is completely different now.